# How to get the two random unique advertisement based on its type?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, random, greatest-n-per-group

In MySQL I have one table called advertisement which contains different type of advertisements like banner and square.

I want exact two random advertisement with different advertisement type.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, ad_type
FROM tbl_advertisement
WHERE ad_type IN ('banner', 'square')
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

It gives me sometime unique ad_type but sometimes not as expected.

```
  [
    RowDataPacket { id: 9, ad_type: 'square' },
    RowDataPacket { id: 8, ad_type: 'square' }
  ]
```

Expected output any two random advertisement with unique ad_type:

```
  [
    RowDataPacket { id: 3, ad_type: 'square' },
    RowDataPacket { id: 4, ad_type: 'banner' }
  ]
```

Comment: use `LIMIT 1` and [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to combine the results of two single advertisements (of different type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses window functions, available in MySQL 8.0:

```
select id, ad_type
from (
    select ad.*, row_number() over(partition by ad_type order by rand()) rn
    from tbl_advertisement ad
    where ad_type in ('banner','square') 
) t
where rn = 1
```

In ealier versions, the simplest option probably is `union all`:

```
(select id, ad_type from tbl_advertisement where ad_type = 'banner' order by rand() limit 1)
union all
(select id, ad_type from tbl_advertisement where ad_type = 'square' order by rand() limit 1)
```

Comment: The first version is maybe not an option or at least not desirable since this query is being called from Node.js application code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I added a solution for earlier versions. What makes you tell that window functions are not an option in node.js?

Comment: a) we don't know if the OP (or future readers) would be using an ORM tool behind MySQL; if so, then window functions are out for certain, b) we also don't know what the OP's MySQL version is